# TYPO3 export/import records tx_news

Tags: import, export, typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I would like to export tx_news records from a running typo3 6.2, tx_news 3.2.4 and import them in a new Server running typo3 9.5 tx_news 7. T3D Export dont work cause there are about 3000 records.
Export/import of the table tx_news_domain_model_news is no problem. I have problems with the related records in table sys_file.

I cant update the running 6.2 site cause FE and BE dont work any more after update.
This site wasnt maintained for about a year now ...

Isnt it possible to export following tables from typo3 6.2 DB with phpmyadmin as SQL:

```
$importTables = [
    'sys_category',
    'sys_category_record_mm',
    'sys_file',
    'sys_file_metadata',
    'sys_file_reference',    
    'tx_news_domain_model_news',
    'tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm',
    'tx_news_domain_model_news_tag_mm',
    'tx_news_domain_model_news_ttcontent_mm',
    'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
    'tx_news_domain_model_link',
];
```

Import these tables with phpmyadmin in the new installation typo3 9.5.
Copy all folders/images in fileadmin/ from old to new server.
Create Folders containing tx_news records in new Typo3 installation and update the 'pid' in table of tx_news_domain_model_news

And after that :

```
Do migration: ./typo3cms news:sync
Sync all images: ./typo3cms news:imagesync
```

?

but i have no idea how to use ./typo3cms with your extension:

> Error: [ Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException
>   ] Command "news:imagesync" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?
>   news:newsimport:run newsimport:run

Comment: Is the 9.5 site new & empty? then you could make an upgrade of the old site and use the desired parts.

Answer (score 2):

That is not trivial but I did that once. Important is that you must still update the 6.2 installation, at least core upgrade + news upgrade. Regarding news: all upgrades are collected in the extension https://github.com/ext-news/news_fal_migration

Then you can use https://github.com/ext-news/news_sync. If you need support there, please contact me in private